# Logout redirect to current page - function

Tags: functions, users, logout

I'm looking for a function that can redirect users when they logout to the current page. I'm looking for a code I can use in `functions.php`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using this code in the `functions.php` does the trick:

```
function wpse_44020_logout_redirect( $logouturl, $redir )
{
    return $logouturl . '&amp;redirect_to=' . get_permalink();
}
add_filter( 'logout_url', 'wpse_44020_logout_redirect', 10, 2 );
```

Note - The above code works only on non-admin pages. To make this work on any page you should replace:

```
return $logouturl . '&amp;redirect_to=' . get_permalink();
```

With:

```
return $logouturl . '&amp;redirect_to=http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url

Easy as adding this:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

Comment: I need it for the function-file. Not as a link, but thanks for the try :)

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy:

```
global $post;
$postid = $post->ID;

$log_out_me = wp_logout_url( get_permalink($postid) );

<a href="'<?php echo $log_out_me; ?>">Logout</a>
```

Now `get_permalink()` is out of the loop.

Answer (score -3):

```
add_filter('logout_url', create_function(false, "return '" .  wp_logout_url(get_option("home")) . "';"));
```

Or change home URL to current page URL.

Comment: Please add some context to this answer - how does it add substance to what amit said a few months back?

Comment: This callback would call itself in an infinite recursion. Please **test** your code before you post it.